# 301 Redirect for website tonight mobile? urls on Apache

Tags: .htaccess

I have a long list of urls like this:

```
http://example.com/site/mobile?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FURL_begins_here.html
```

and no matter what I do, I can't get the urls to go to the new pages.

Any ideas, I'm dying here.

Comment: `%2F` is not allowed in Apache by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} URL_begins_here.html
RewriteRule .? http://example.com/new-url-goes-here.html? [R=301,L]
```